# Horizontal RecyclerView inside Vertical RecyclerView not receive touches

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a next layout configuration:

`CoordinatorLayout
  AppbarLayout
  RecyclerView`

RecyclerView has a first item which is horizontal RecyclerView.
When i scroll down till horizontal Recycler fully dissapears and then i scroll up till it becomes fully visible and try to scroll or tap on it it's not scroll nor receives any touch events at the first time. But next time it works as intended. 
I suppose that something is intercepting touch events.
Here is test project
https://github.com/outofdate/recyclertest

**EDITED**

Found how to fix
https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2

Comment: please provide your Adapter code here. do you think ppl have time to look into your whole code and find where you implement RecylerView?

Comment: that's not an adapter related issue, it's most likely CoordinatorLayout/AppbarLayout/RecyclerView and coordinator behaviour related.